# How to Add Image Field in CIVICRM

Tags: drupal, custom-fields, webform-civicrm, images

I am trying to add an Image as Custom field in Civicrm Contact, but the Image Field type is not in the Custom Field section. It has only Field type as File.

How to apply Drupal Image styles for Images uploaded on Civicrm Contact.

I have integrated Civicrm in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there's no custom field type specifically for images. You can of course put an image in a file field type. Interestingly, the image field that is available for organizations is technically there for all contact types, just not enabled for individuals, so I'd guess it wouldn't be hard to turn it on.

To display images from CiviCRM in Drupal, I use views and the external image cache module here: https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_external

It's a useful technique from Chris Burgess, who describes how to use it here: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34929.0

Comment: I had a go at using this technique. CiviCRM now uses a checksum for image displays. The effect is that a new file is created in the imagecache folder everytime the image is served, using imagecache external. This sort of defeats the purpose  and can quite rapidly fill up storage space.

Comment: Alan - do you have any thoughts about getting around Tony's concerns

Comment: I believe the drupal integration no longer requires the use of imagecache_external, you can use the image field in views and apply the drupal image styles to them on display.